# MYSQL CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a dilemma, what will be the result of the following SQL query and how it works:

```
SELECT ...
CASE 
     WHEN (a.FIELD=1 AND b.FIELD=2) THEN 1
     WHEN (a.FIELD=1 AND b.FIELD=3) THEN 3
     WHEN (b.FIELD=2 AND c.FIELD=1) THEN 0
        END) 

..

FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.FOREIGN_KEY
LEFT JOIN c ON b.ID = c.FOREIGN_KEY

WHERE <conditions>
```

So basically there are more conditions that is true for the CASE statement.
How MySQL evaluates them? Will be the result the first TRUE   condition, or the last?

thanks

PS: I was looking in the MySQL documentation but i found no hint for that.

Answer (score 2):

The first matching condtition wins.

> [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)
>
> ```
> CASE
>     WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
>     [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END CASE
> ```
>
> **each WHEN clause search_condition expression is evaluated until one is true**, at which point its corresponding THEN clause statement_list executes. If no search_condition is equal, the ELSE clause statement_list executes, if there is one.